# FIlter() is not functioning when it's variable updates. how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

i am creating a chat application, where message variable is coming from another component. i want to filter the messages according to their room id

so i used useEffect to update the roomMessage variable everytime message updates. the message variable updates, but the roomMessage is not updating and the new messages are not showing in the screen. is it the filter() function's problem or what?

```
export default function Chat_body() {

///messages has all the message data
    let {userName,userID,messages} = useContext(AuthContext);

    const {roomID} = useParams();
    const [roomMessages,setRoomMessages] = useState(messages.filter((message) => message.room === parseInt(roomID)).reverse())

     useEffect(() => {
        
         setRoomMessages(messages.filter((message) => message.room === parseInt(roomID)).reverse())
         console.log(roomMessages)

       }, [roomID,messages]);

      

      
   

  return (
    <div className="chat_body">

        {roomMessages.map((message)=>{
            
            return(

                
                
      {roomMessages.map((message)=>{
            
            return(

                
                
        <div key={message.id} className={userName===message.sender ? "chat_message recieved" :"chat_message"}>
            <span className='avatar_span'><MdAccountCircle/></span>
            <div className={userName===message.sender ? "message chat_recieved" : "message"}>
                <span className='chat_name'>{message.sender}</span>
                <div className={userName===message.sender ? "sent_message  chat_reciever" : "sent_message"}>
                    <p>{message.message}</p>
                    <span className='timeSpan'>{message.sent_at}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                )

        })}
    )
}
```

context.js

```
import React,{createContext,useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import pusherJs from 'pusher-js';


const endpointMessage = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/message'
 const [messages,setMessages] = useState([])



 useEffect(()=>{
     const pusher = new pusherJs('f12d9df33bdc80d7947b', {
      cluster: 'ap2'
    });

    var channel = pusher.subscribe('chat');
    channel.bind('message', function(data) {
      setMessages([...messages,data]);
      console.log(messages)
    });

    return ()=>{
      channel.unbind_all();
      channel.unsubscribe();
    }
  },[messages])
```

if I map the message variable, all the messages shows, and renders the updated messages as well but when I try to filter them, the new messages doesn't show!

Comment: Hello Naim, you need to provide more information to get a better help; for example what it the context provides us.

but something.filter is not a functions generally means: messages are not an array in first place.

Comment: First of all console.log(roomMessages) immediately after setting wont return the updated value.
Try to store the filtered array in a variable and then setState so you can check the variable if its returning things properly

Comment: i updated and added the context js. please check out

Comment: @vatsalsoni i am rendering the message in my page by mapping out. the updated message is not showing there either, idk, if it's the console that's causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

```js
useEffect(() => {
  setRoomMessages( prevMessage => {
    return prevMessage.filter(message => message.room === parseInt(roomID).reverse())
  })
  console.log(roomMessages)
}, [roomID,messages]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the **useState** and **useEffect** hooks from **Chat_body** component and filter the **messages** from the context directly. (You also have used map twice, which is not needed). It should look something like this:

```
export default function Chat_body() {
  ///messages has all the message data
  let { userName, messages } = useContext(AuthContext);

  const { roomID } = useParams();

  const filteredMessages = messages.filter((message) => message.room === parseInt(roomID)).reverse();
  const isSender = userName === message.sender;

  return (
    <div className="chat_body">
      {filteredMessages.map((message) => (
        <div key={message.id} className={isSender ? 'chat_message recieved' : 'chat_message'}>
          <span className="avatar_span">
            <MdAccountCircle />
          </span>

          <div className={isSender ? 'message chat_recieved' : 'message'}>
            <span className="chat_name">{message.sender}</span>

            <div className={isSender ? 'sent_message  chat_reciever' : 'sent_message'}>
              <p>{message.message}</p>
              <span className="timeSpan">{message.sent_at}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out.
the problem was that, the datatype of roomID received by useParams and the message.room wasn't the same. which is why, everytime I was filtering with the condition of

```js
message.room === roomID
```

it was not returning true. i had to make it

```js
prevMessage.filter(message => message.room == parseInt(roomID).reverse())
```

with "==" to make it work. I am extremely sorry for giving everyone a hard time for such stupid mistake and thank you all for helping me out.